# How to represent Core Data optional Scalars (Bool/Int/Double/Float) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

(first noticed on: Xcode 8.2.1, iOS 10, Swift 3)
(still present as of: Xcode 9 beta 3, iOS11, Swift 4)

We all know that the `Core Data` concept of `optionals` precedes and is not strictly tied to the `Swift` concept of `optionals`.

And we have accepted that even if a `Core Data` attribute is marked as `Non-optional`, the auto-generated `NSManagedObject` subclass has an `optional` type:

[image]
(some people manually remove the `?` with no adverse effects, some don't, but that's beside the point)

(From here on the example and screenshots are for `Bool` properties, but same goes for `Int16/32/64`, `Double`, `Float`)

Now I noticed the reverse - when a `Core Data` attribute of type `Bool` is marked as `Optional` (and `Use Scalar Type` is chosen, which Xcode does by default), the auto-generated class has a variable of a `non-optional` type.

[image]

Does this make sense? Is it a bug? Is the behaviour documented anywhere?

And most importantly - how do I actually represent an optional `Bool`?

I can think of some work-arounds, but they don't seem ideal (e.g. not using scalars, but going back to `NSNumber` representation of the `Bool`. Or (even worse) having a separate `Bool` called something like `isVerified_isSet`)

---

Note: I did a couple more tests and if the `Default Value` is set to `None` or to `NO`, then the variable gets saved as `false` (even if I never actually assign it in my code). If the `Default Value` is set to `YES`, then the variable gets saved as `true`. Still, this means that (apparently) there is no way to logically represent this variable as not having been set yet.

Comment: Did you solve how to represent Bool attribute as not having been set yet?

Comment: @Shamsiddin - There is no change / fix from Apple's side - so you would still need to either use a workaround (helper `isSet` properties) or perhaps the suggestions from the article linked in Arek's answer.

Comment: One of the temporary solutions I think would be use of `Integer 16` (`NSNumber` in entity's class file) with `0` and `1` values instead of `Boolean` (`NSNumber`) `true/false`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I see the same thing, and I consider it to be a bug. It's not documented anywhere that I can find. Apparently Core Data is applying Objective-C style assumptions here, where a boolean defaults to `NO`, and an integer defaults to 0. The Core Data/Swift interface has some rough edges, and this is one I hadn't considered before.

It's a good find but I think you're stuck with it until Apple addresses it. You already know the best workarounds, which I agree aren't great. I recommend filing a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually until you mention it I didn't even realise that the same 'issue' happens for all Scalar types, not only `Bool`. (I've now amended the original question to mention that).

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. Core Data is objective-c under the hood, so expect objective-c behavior until a swifty Core Data is released.

Comment: Lots of Apple frameworks are ObjC under the hood, but if Swift is supported for use with them, they should present Swifty interfaces.

Answer (score 13):

This happens because Objective-C scalar types do not have a notion of nil value. Source: [handling-core-data-optional-scalar-attributes](http://aplus.rs/2017/handling-core-data-optional-scalar-attributes/)

Answer (score 10):

I would rather use Objective-C types to manage these cases than Swift types.
In these cases, for scalars types, you can use NSNumber.

```
 @NSManaged public var myDouble: NSNumber?
```

In the model myDouble is an optional double with nil value by default.

To get the real value you only need to use:

```
myEntity.myDouble?.doubleValue
```

Comment: That is still optional. You did not solve anything

Comment: The question is how to represent optional scalars values, so to use an optional NSNumber is a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up here with this:

```
@NSManaged var boolAttribute: Bool
```

and it is not being seen in Objective-C, *and* you have already disabled "Optional" and enabled "Use Scalar Type" on those attributes, then do yourself a favour.

**Double check you have imported your Swift bridging header into that Objective-C file.**

I did not and, well, I was most of the way to changing my Bools to NSNumbers before smacking my head and realising how foolish I had been.