# Set NONE to Boolean in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, nonetype

My core data contains a field of Optional Bool (scalar) which can take True/False/None.
[image: Core data]

The problem is I don't know how to set the NONE type to the field since it is not allowed to assign the `nil` to the value., i.e the following does not work:

```
dog.gender = nil
```

> 'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'Bool'

If I uncheck the Scalar type, then I got another problem.

> `Cannot assign value of type 'NSNumber?' to type 'Bool?'

Comment: A “scalar type” cannot be nil, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42622638/1187415. If you uncheck that option then the attribute is represented as NSNumber and you can set it to nil.

Comment: Thanks, after unchecking the option, I have another problem `Cannot assign value of type 'NSNumber?' to type 'Bool?'`

Comment: You must *convert* the (optional) NSNumber back to an (optional) Bool, e.g. `let gender = dog.gender?.boolValue?`

Comment: Thanks! @MartinR