# Optional Double attributes in CoreData don't behave like optionals?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a problem by using some Double attributes for my CoreData entity. Other attributes which are of type Int, String, Date, etc. can be nil (they are optionals) but it seems like Double attributes aren't optionals, even though the attribute is marked with optional in the graphical editor (see attached photo):

[image]

But in code the `myDouble` attribute behaves like a non optional attribute:

[image]

So what am I missing?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you regenerated NSManagedObject subclass ?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/42622638/1187415 ?

Comment: @MartinR No. So there isn't a clean and "easy" solution to this?

Comment: @MikeHaydan. No

Comment: @finebel you can try by regenerating of `NSManagedObject` subclass, maybe this will help. Because  you've changed the attribute in `.xcdatamodel` but didn't regenerate the subclass, and it shows previous one

Comment: @finebel you can generate it as non-scalar type (`NSNumber?`) and then in extension declare scalar interface to it.

Comment: @finebel But click the link that MartinR gave you and read what it says. Your entire question is based on a misconception. The word "optional" with your red arrow has nothing to do with Swift Optional types.

Comment: Thanks for all of your reply! I will give it a try...